Failed to convert parameter value from a string to a guid
I have a simple query to get a USER record based on the ID supplied as parameter:
SELECT 
    ID,
    SURNAME, NAME, INITIALS, USERNAME,
    EMAIL 
FROM 
    dbo.[USER]
WHERE 
    (ID = @ID)

(My ID column is of data type uniqueidentifier).
When I try to test this query in FillBy by supplying an existing ID from the USER table, I get this error:

Any idea what to do here?
